# how to comment code blocks (that you want to remove)in the code page word press

Tags: hook, disable

I need to disable best selling featured products etc.

```
    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: You should add some more things to elaborate this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do that. Here is an example

`<!--div>Here are some elements</div-->`
Another way is :

```
<?php /*echo "<div>
Here 
are some 
details
</div>" */;?>
```

Comment: * @hooked shopper_best_selling_products - 30

Comment: @user218830 please elaborate on what you want to say.

Comment: Im sorry i have no idea about code but learning, I have a webpage and it shows these lines like best sellers etc. What i need is to know how to block that line from showing like the best selling items on my homepage.

Comment: Try one of my solutions please. If you are new at coding then you are advised to learn.